# FFMPEG - How can I add black bars to top and bottom of my video?

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line

I have about 100 videos. I would like to add a 30 pixel horizontal black bar to the top and bottom of each video without ruining the dimenions(so even if they go over the video). How can I achieve this? Also what's the command to have it run on every video in the folder without doing it for each one? I'm a complete beginner and I'm lost. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/q/12105/21971

Comment: OS - Windows, macOS?

Answer (score 6):

### Adding Bars

You can do it with a combination of the *[crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop)* & *[pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad)* video filters:

```
-filter:v crop="in_w:in_h-60:0:30",pad="in_w:in_h+60:0:-30"
```

Both filters use the same format: *width:height:x-offset:y-offset*

In the *crop* filter, you want width to be same as the video's input width (you can use the variable ***in_w***). You want to crop 60 pixels (30*2) from the input height (*in_h-60*). X offset stays at zero so nothing is changed horizontally. And set the Y offset to 30 so that 30 pixels are cropped from the top & bottom each. Otherwise, it will just crop 60 pixels from the bottom.

In the *pad* filter, the ***in_w*** & ***in_h*** variables will be whatever is output from the *crop* filter (you can just replace these with the actual video dimensions if you prefer). Use ***in_w*** again to preserve horizontal dimension. Add 60 black pixels back to the vertial dimension (*in_h+60*). Leave the X offset at *0* & set Y offset to *-30* so pixels are added at top & bottom. Otherwise, it will just add 60 pixels to bottom.

The other option, as I think @Quertiy was pointing out, is to create a PNG image the same dimensions as your video with black bars at the top & bottom, & transparent in the middle, then overlay it onto the image:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "overlay" -c:v libx264 "out.mp4"
```

It may be wise to list the streams in the filter arguments: `-filter_complex "[0:0][1:0]overlay"`

---

### Multiple Files

If you were using a Unix shell (I believe this is what MacOS uses), you could use a *for* loop to convert all videos in a directory:

```
for V in *; do ffmpeg -i "$V" -c:v libx264 -filter:v crop="in_w:in_h-60:0:30",pad="in_w:in_h+60:0:-30" "padded-$V"; done
```

But I'm not sure what the equivalent is using the Windows command prompt.

**Edit:** [Windows command prompt has a *for* loop as well](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1154761&seqNum=10). So it should be something like:

```
for %V in (*) do ffmpeg -i "%V" -c:v libx264 -filter:v crop="in_w:in_h-60:0:30",pad="in_w:in_h+60:0:-30" "padded-%V"
```

But, I haven't tested it.

**Note:** Use ***%%V*** within batch files, ***%V*** if using the command prompt directly.

**Edit:** According to [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2754/parsing-all-the-files-in-a-directory-using-powershell/), you should be able to do it in Windows PowerShell like this:

```
foreach ($V in Get-ChildItem .\) {ffmpeg -i "$V" -c:v libx264 -filter:v crop="in_w:in_h-60:0:30",pad="in_w:in_h+60:0:-30" "padded-$V"}
```

Again, I haven't fully tested it.

Comment: Somewhat faster would be to apply drawbox twice. `drawbox=iw:30:0:0:t=fill,drawbox=iw:30:0:ih-30:t=fill`

Comment: Much faster is using fillborders filter.

Comment: This really helped blacking out subtitles when I needed to re-sub. in another language.